# Implementing My Own Coloring in a ListPlot of a List of Lists

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, color, customization

I have a list of lists, for example:

```
list[1] = {{10, 20}, {400, 500}, {450, 602}, {580, 700}, {700, 
830}, {810, 920}}

 For[i = 2, i <= 4, i++,

  list[i] = list[1] + Table[{RandomReal[{-30, 30}], 0}, {i, 1, 6}]
    ]
```

And I ListPlot all of them together:

```
ListPlot[Table[list[i], {i, 1, 4}], PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 100}, 
AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 500]
```

Listplot implements it's own coloring, giving every list a separate color. However, I want to color the first entries of every list a certain color, say red, the second entries green, the third blue and so on. Is there some kind of plotstyle option to do that within ListPlot? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It seems quite a hack, but it works:

```
Needs["PolygonPlotMarkers`"]
markers[size_] := Block[{
    colors = {Red, Green, Blue, Orange, Purple, Pink},
    shapes = {"Disk", "Square", "Diamond", "UpTriangle"}}, 
   Flatten[Table[
     Graphics[{FaceForm[color], EdgeForm[], 
       PolygonMarker[shape, Offset[size]]}], {color, colors}, {shape, 
      shapes}]]];

ListPlot[Flatten[Table[{list[i][[j]]}, {j, 1, 6}, {i, 1, 4}], 1], 
 PlotMarkers -> markers[10], AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Note that in the definition of `markers`, `colors` has the same length as your individual lists and `shapes` the same length as the number of lists. You can certainly do this also with regular font-based markers, but then you can't rely on their positioning.

Answer (score 3):

```
data = Table[list[i], {i, 1, 4}];
colors = {Red, Green, Blue, Orange, Cyan, Purple};
```

**Restructuring input data**

Transpose the input data, plot each part separately and combine with `Show`:

```
Show[ListPlot[List /@ #, PlotStyle -> #2, 
    PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}, ImageSize -> 400] & @@@ 
  Transpose[{Transpose[data], colors}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Post-Processing:**

Post-process the original `ListPlot` output to re-color the markers:

```
ListPlot[data, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}, ImageSize -> 400] /. 
    {directives___, inset : __Inset} :> {directives, Transpose[{colors, {inset}}]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively, define a function for post-processing with user-provided colors:

```
postProcess[cl : (_Integer | _List) : 1] := Module[{col = 
     If[Head[cl] === Integer, ColorData[cl, "ColorList"], 
      cl]}, # /. {dir___, inset : __Inset} :> {dir, 
      Transpose[{col[[;; Length[{inset}]]], {inset}}]}] &
```

Examples:

```
plt = ListPlot[data, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}, ImageSize -> 400];

postProcess[colors] @ plt
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
postProcess[] @ plt
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
postProcess[3] @ plt
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]